# Looking for idiom/expression to describe an instance where one makes something seem better than it really is

Tags: idioms, expressions

Maybe the example would help to describe the expression I am looking for:

Say - a  sub-par school or organization makes a promotional video, whereby they make the school look way better than it really is. They accomplished this  by interviewing a few successful students,  showing only the best parts of the school/classes, picking a few angles, and omitting 80% of what really represents the true situation.

I have heard the following expression, but not sure whether it's appropriate, or even phrased correctly:

> Turn chicken into a chicken soup.

EDIT: actually the expression was

> Make chicken salad out of chicken $#!%"

coined by Brock Lesnar. Obviously it's less befitting than others mentioned on the thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The one I like best is **polishing a turd**.

Comment: +1 for "real" slang that we probably won't be hearing from politicians at the hustings anytime soon.

Comment: Also [You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+can't+make+a+silk+purse+out+of+a+sow's+ear), though that focusses more on the futility of the action, rather than misleading presentation. And [mutton dressed as lamb](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mutton+dressed+as+lamb) is normally only applied to older women wearing clothes more suited to younger ones. But at least you can say them in polite society.

Answer (score 9):

I would consider *cherry pick* and *golden sample*;  both involve the selection of a nonrepresentative group to give the best impression.

Not precisely an idiom, but an expression that may be easy to overlook is *false advertising*.

Also related: *spin* and its derivative terms. These usually have negative connotations; compare *put a spin on*, *spin doctors*, etc.

Answer (score 7):

One common long-standing expression that comes to mind is **window dressing**, but there must be hundreds of well-known dismissive put-downs for "promotional exaggeration".

As a Brit, I'd just settle for the understated **selective reporting** in OP's example.

Answer (score 7):

Try *putting lipstick on a pig*.

The school could also be said to be indulging in *smoke and mirrors*.

Answer (score 5):

One common idiom is "make a mountain out of a molehill", however the underlying implication of that is "make a problem bigger than it really is", which is kind of the opposite of what you are looking for.

Another common idiom is "putting lipstick on a pig", which means make something that is really bad seem to look a lot better. That might be a good fit for you.

As to the chicken soup one -- I've never heard that expression, Google hasn't either.

Comment: You should probably put the molehill one after the lipstick one, or take it out altogether, then.

Comment: To *put lipstick on a pig* is very much an Americanism that's only shot to prominence in the last couple of decades. As a Brit, perhaps I shouldn't comment, but I think it's almost exclusively used by Texans and politicians.

Comment: I don't think it is exclusive to either Texans or politicians, although recent political events brought it to the fore. I have heard it a lot in all sorts of contexts. I'll grant you though that I don't remember hearing it much in the UK. Interestingly, the person I remember using it most was a Belorussian I used to work with. Which doesn't prove anything of course, but is nonetheless a "strange but true."

Comment: Well, I did say that as a Brit I probably really shouldn't comment. We only hear it from US politicians & pundits on the news. So I doubt it'll ever "hit the streets" on this side of the pond, because those are the last kind of people users of new slang expressions would want to emulate.

Answer (score 5):

In the song *Things Are Seldom What They Seem* in the operetta *HMS Pinafore*, there are the lines:

> *Gild the farthing if you will*
>   
> *Yet it is a farthing still*.

I had always assumed this referred to a standing expression, but just now I wasn't able to find any other references to *gilding the farthing*, other than ones explicitly referencing that song. There does appear to have been a 1963 book by Brian Almond called *Gild the Brass Farthing*.

Comment: Welcome aboard the site. An upvote to get you started.

Comment: +1; more commonly ["gild the lily"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gild_the_lily)

Answer (score 3):

An historical reference or metaphor would be a [*Potemkin village*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potemkin_village). These were false village façades (think Western movie sets) that were, according to legend, set up by Grigory Potemkin to impress the Empress Catherine. Generally viewed as fable, you’ll still hear the reference occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use is *puffery*; that is, puffing up the best features of the school and pointedly ignoring the worse ones.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs to me that a less colloquial term would be *self-aggrandizement*. The OED just has it as “the action or process of promoting oneself as being powerful or important”, but thefreedictionary.com supports my feeling that there is a connotation of exaggeration:

> the act or practice of enhancing or exaggerating one’s own importance, power, or reputation.

(Sorry I didn’t put that in my earlier post; it’s been on the tip of my tongue for three days.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps employment of or resorting to:

- selective memory
- selective history
- selective representation

For example:

> Putting its best *feet* forward, the alumni testimonials in behalf of **No’Rs Nurturing Academy** were seen by regulators as partly true, largly selective representation.

Answer (score 1):

There is also this saying which doesn't fit exactly your criteria but it illustrates perfectly the concept that not everything you see can be trusted.

*All that glitters is not gold*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_that_glitters_is_not_gold

Answer (score 0):

*Gilding the lily* is another option.

Answer (score 0):

In certain contexts I would just call it false advertising, but I came across a compound that to me sounds more like an expression:

**vainglory**

Here are the definitions of *vainglory*, together with an example of how it is used, given by the [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vainglory):

> **1 :**  excessive or ostentatious pride especially in one's achievements
>
> **2 :**  vain display or show :  vanity
>
> **Example:** "...the vainglory that nations have historically shown after they have achieved military supremacy..."

Comment: A suggestion is not an answer. An answer which consists of virtually nothing but a citation is not useful and may be subject to deletion even if it is correct. Excessive pride is not what OP is looking for. OP is looking for an expression that means overselling something.

Comment: I added block-quote formatting to your answer to indicate the language that came from another source, and I added a linked citation of that source. In future answers that include quotations from other sources, please try to include these elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***make a silk purse (out) of a sow's ear***

> (*idiomatic*) To produce something refined, admirable, or valuable from something which is unrefined, unpleasant, or of little or no value.
>
> [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_a_silk_purse_of_a_sow%27s_ear)